# Why are accounts which sign up newsletter during registration has Type as Guest?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, newsletter

I notice that when a customer signs up a **new** account and checks the *Sign up newsletter* option during registration, Magento puts this account under the `Marketing > Newsletter Subscribers` in the admin panel.

However, these accounts which signed up newsletter during registration are put into the Newsletter Subscribers list without names and Type column incorrectly shown as Guest.

[image]

Strangely, if the user updates his account information such his name, the user's Type will be updated to Customer on the Newsletter Subscribers page.

Why doesn't Magento populate the customer's name which was entered during registration in the Newsletter Subscribers page? Since the customer is already signing up an account, why is the *Type* categorised as Guest but not Customer?

Is this a bug in Magento2? How can I fix it?